# Create Table For Db Created On SQL Server

Tags: python, sql

I would like to know how to create a table for a Db created with python on SQL Server 2019 ?
I tried something like under, but it creates table on MASTER and not into my Db I've just created before...

```
    mydb2 = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host='DELL-G3\SQLEXPRESS', db=dbname)
    cursor = mydb2.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
       CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Janvier (
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          Date INTEGER,
          Nom TEXT,
          Prix FLOAT
          );
    """)
```

Comment: Does your version of SQL Server 2019 support `create table if not exists`?

Comment: I have no experience with pyodbc, but your connection string doesn't seem [right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Nope, it doesn't support "if not exists"...

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yep I forgot the + But it works.

Comment: HI I succeeded !!! Thanks everyone !!!